# Segmentation fault while using ffi to convert lua strings to C strings

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

I met a strange problem whne tying to convert a Lua string to C char arry.

```
local str = "1234567890abcdef"
local ffi = require "ffi"
ffi.cdef[[
    int printf(const char *fmt, ...);
]]
print(#str)
print(str)
local cstr = ffi.new("unsigned char[?]", #str, str)
```

run this code get:

```
[root@origin ~]# luajit test.lua 
16
1234567890abcdef
Segmentation fault
```

I know `ffi.new("unsigned char[?]", #str+1, str)` will solve this, but I dont know why.

I don't think it is the `\0` problem because I found some strange point.

- if `str` is not 16 bytes, this will not happen.
- if I delete `ffi.cdef` which I didn't use , this will not happen.
- if I put `ffi.cdef` behind the `ffi.new` ,this will not happen .

  ```
  [root@origin ~]# luajit test.lua
  17
  1234567890abcdefg
  // this is the result that I only append a 'g' to `str`.
  ```

I tried on Luajit 2.0.5 and Luajit 2.1.0-beta3 with default compiler arguments.

So, is there anyone knows how this happen, thanks.

Comment: This problem is due to lack of place for terminating zero.  You must use `#str+1`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I don't think so, can you explain why it only happen on converting a 16 bytes string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly because of string size is 17 but array allocated only for 16 bytes. https://github.com/LuaJIT/LuaJIT/blob/0c0e7b168ea147866835954267c151ef789f64fb/src/lj_cconv.c#L582 is the code that copies string to resulting array. As you can see, if target is array and its size is smaller than string length, it shrinks string; however your type is VLA (variable-length array), and for VLA size is not specified (it is `2**32-1`, actually, which is way bigger than 17).

"I don't get error if" is not an argument here - you stomp memory that is used for something else. Sometimes stomping extra byte with 0 is not fatal (e.g. due to alignment this byte wasn't used anyway, or just happened to be 0 already) or doesn't result in hard crash - it doesn't make it correct.